# How to suppress cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option -Wno-implicit-fallthrough

Tags: gcc, suppress-warnings, gcc6

I'm running `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wno-implicit-fallthrough ...` with gcc 6.3.0 on Linux, and I'm getting the message:

```
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-implicit-fallthrough’
```

How can I suppress this message? I do want to specify `-Wno-implicit-fallthrough` though, it's useful when the code is compiled with newer versions of gcc. So I want `-Wno-implicit-fallthrough` to take effect if available; otherwise there should be no warnings like the above displayed.